# Rectangle matrix calculations in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I had a generalized question to find out if it was possible or not to do matrix calculations on a rectangle. I have a CvRect that has information stored in it with coordinates and I have a cvMat that has transformational data. What I would like to know is if there was a way to get the Rect to use the matrix data to generate a rotated, skewed, and repositioned rectangle out of it. I've searched online, but I was only able to get information on image transforms.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. cv::Rect is also not capable of that, as it only describes rectangles in a Manhattan world. There is cv::RotatedRect, but this also does not handle skewing.

You can, however, feed the corner points of your rectangle to cv::transform:
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=transform#cv2.transform

You will then obtain four points that are transformed accordingly. Note that there are also more specialized versions of this function, e.g. warpPerspective() and warpAffine().

Comment: I took a look at WarpPerspective but it asks for a CvArr*. Not sure if it would've let me pass in a CvRect in there since the OpenCV documentation only specify that a CvArr, CvMat, and a IplImage would be the only data members valid. Also how would I be able to pass in the 4 different points into either functions?

Comment: No it is not possible to pass a Rect at all. You need to build a Mat containing the four points first. Use a two-channel matrix or 3-channel matrix (third channel set to 1) to store the points in there.

Comment: Can I get an example of the point to matrix conversion? I've tried to create a matrix with the points, but when doing the Transform I've had it crash on me. I've created a 2x2 matrix using "CvMat* pointMat = cvCreateMat(2, 2, CV_32F);" Next I set the point information using "cvSetReal2D" I've also verified the data in the matrix exists. When I ran the transform function I had it crash on me though. The parameters I used were "cvTransform(pointMat, pointMat, H, 0);" where 'H' is a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I figured out my issue. It made more sense for me to create my own Rectangle classes that store information based on the 4 points and work on the math that way instead of trying to figure out how OpenCV handled everything. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yeah, I also always tend to use what's "already there" but sometimes you still end up doing it on your own. OpenCV seems to be no big help for handling rectangles..